# Building BST Recursion Depth Exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

New here, so apologies for any broken decorum. I'm trying to write code for a BST that has a method that builds the BST using a sorted array. I keep getting the `RecursionError: Maximum recursion depth exceeded.` First time posting because I feel so lost :( Appreciate any help.

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, sorted_array):
        self.root = None
        self.sorted_array=sorted_array


    def build_tree(self, sorted_array):
        if not self.sorted_array:
            return None
        mid = len(sorted_array) // 2
        root = Node(self.sorted_array[mid])
        root.left = self.build_tree(self.sorted_array[0:mid])
        root.right = self.build_tree(self.sorted_array[mid + 1:])
        return root

example_array=[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 23, 67, 324, 6345]

my_tree=BinarySearchTree()

my_tree.build_tree(example_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `build_tree` method, `sorted_array` and `self.sorted_array` are not the same object. You can fix this by using `sorted_array` everywhere, there does not appear to be any reason to keep a self reference anyway.

It might be helpful to use a debugger to step through the code to figure out problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so much aware of Python syntax, though I can smell something messy here :

```
    root.left = self.build_tree(self.sorted_array[0:mid])
```

you can't always start slicing from `0` (0 is not constant), rather you can use following modification in your code, which will iterate current start position of the array:

```
    root.left = self.build_tree(self.sorted_array[:mid])
```

you can learn more about python slicing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8359623) thread.